# Converting Dataframe to RDD reduces partitions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In our code, Dataframe was created as :

```
DataFrame DF = hiveContext.sql("select * from table_instance");
```

When I convert my dataframe to rdd and try to get its number of partitions as

```
RDD<Row> newRDD = Df.rdd();
System.out.println(newRDD.getNumPartitions());
```

It reduces the number of partitions to 1(1 is printed in the console). Originally my dataframe has 102 partitions .

**UPDATE:**

While reading , I repartitoned the dataframe :

```
DataFrame DF = hiveContext.sql("select * from table_instance").repartition(200);
```

and then converted to rdd , so it gave me 200 partitions only. 
Does

> JavaSparkContext

has a role to play in this? When we convert a dataframe to rdd , is default minimum partitions flag also considered at the spark context level?

UPDATE:

I made a seperate sample program in which I read the exact same table into dataframe and converted to rdd. No extra stage was created for RDD conversion and the partition count was also correct. I am now wondering what different am I doing in my main program.

Please let me know if my understanding is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

It basically depends on the implementation of `hiveContext.sql()`. Since I am new to Hive, my guess is `hiveContext.sql` doesn't know OR is not able to split the data present in the table.

For example, when you read a text file from HDFS, spark context considers the number of blocks used by that file to determine the partitions.

What you did with `repartition` is the obvious solution for these kinds of problems.(Note: repartition may cause a shuffle operation if proper partitioner is not used, hash Partitioner is used by default)

Coming to your doubt, hiveContext may consider the default minimum partition property. But, relying on default property is not going to
solve all your problems. For instance, if your hive table's size increases, your program still uses the default number of partitions.

**Update: Avoid shuffle during repartition**

Define your custom partitioner:

```
public class MyPartitioner extends HashPartitioner {
    private final int partitions;
    public MyPartitioner(int partitions) {
        super();
        this.partitions = partitions;
    }
    @Override
    public int numPartitions() {
        return this.partitions;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPartition(Object key) {
        if (key instanceof String) {
            return super.getPartition(key);
        } else if (key instanceof Integer) {
            return (Integer.valueOf(key.toString()) % this.partitions);
        } else if (key instanceof Long) {
            return (int)(Long.valueOf(key.toString()) % this.partitions);
        }
        //TOD ... add more types
    }
}
```

Use your custom partitioner:

```
JavaPairRDD<Long, SparkDatoinDoc> pairRdd = hiveContext.sql("select *   from table_instance")
.mapToPair( //TODO ... expose the column as key)

rdd = rdd.partitionBy(new MyPartitioner(200));
//... rest of processing
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @code. I have been stuck on this issue for sometime now. The partitions from hivecontext.sql() are getting read as 102. I launched a count action on dataframe and came to know that 102 tasks are getting launched and thus 102 partitions. Now when I am doing repartition ,it's causing lots of shuffle. I want to do a repartition based on some columns, please suggest a repartition technique which can do minimum shuffle

Comment: Could you explain what type of column it is and what's it's range of values?

Comment: That are basically decided by user . It can be a string , long , bigint any data type of column can be present

Comment: Repartitioning a dataframe can not be done like this. Secondly hivecontext.sql returns a dataframe and not a pair rdd . For using this though I will have to convert dataframe to rdd then call this custom partitioner on this rdd with one partition and thus one task launched. It will again give me memory issues.

Comment: Since I am new to hive, I have commented the part of converting dataframe to rdd. Also, once you convert dataframe to rdd, you need to run the `mapToPair()` on it and select any column as key, and entire row as value.
According to my understating above code will not give memory issue because spark can pipeline the partitioning process. Please run the code and confirm.

Comment: can you explain why this will cause less shuffling

Comment: Spark tries to avoid shuffling. But actions that operate per `key` like join, groupBy etc require shuffling. So, if you have any action that requires shuffling and if your RDD is already partitioned according to `key` (in your case column), then it doesn't have to shuffle again.

Comment: But if my job fails while repartitioning only then I have no other way left. My point of asking you this is that how does your code works better then normal hashpartitioner

Comment: Performance wise, use of HashPartitioner and my code are same. But I gave the example of custom partitioner because you mentioned about different columns. Let's say you have a reduce operation per some integer column that represents age and you want to process all rows that belong to age groups 11 to 20, 21 to 30, 31 to 40 etc. You can customize the partition operation in these scenarios.

Comment: thanks @code but repartitioning the dataframe or the pairRDD gives the same results and throws memory excpetion. I tried your solution too. It looks like I need to figure out a way to preserve partitions in the df to rdd conversion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132551/discussion-between-code-and-aviral-kumar).

Comment: please ping in the chat